# Reducing the size of Random Forest tree plot in R

Tags: r, random-forest

I plotted random forest tree using reprtree package as below,

```
model23 <- randomForest(active ~ total_gross_amt + frequency + t_shirt, data = mydata)
reprtree:::plot.getTree(model23)
```

Random Forest Tree Plot :

[image]

But I am not able to interpret anything from the tree.

Is there anyway by which the tree size could be reduced or any other method by which a single random forest tree could be plotted in R with code?

Thanks in advance.
Balaji

Comment: can you share your data? try `dput(mydata)`

Comment: I can not share the data due to its sensitive nature.

Answer (score 0):

2 years late, but it might help someone else.

Go to plots tab > export > save as image > width = 1500, height =  900, don't forget to tick "view plot after saving" and click save